How to keep the data I loaded while debuging with spyder?
Imagine that I have a program that is just like that:
open(bigfile)
bigfile.load(hugevariable)
plot(hugevariable)

and that I want to keep the "hugevariable" loaded in memory while debugging the plot.
How can I do that with the spyder debugger?
Loading the variable takes a tremendous amount of time and I don't want to do it everytime when I debug the plot.
PS: I don't want to separate my program in two parts saving the data in a first program and loading it in a second. I know this may be a solution.

What do you mean with "while debugging the plot"? If your program exits, the data it has loaded is of course lost from memory and needs to be loaded again...

I want that the program do not exit and just comes back as how it was right before the plot.

If you want your program to not exit, you can e.g. wrap it in an infinite loop. while True: plot(hugevariable); input("Hit enter to plot again...")?

@AKX "If your program exits, the data it has loaded is of course lost from memory and needs to be loaded again" If the OP has the Spyder IDE open and runs their script then when the script finishes the IDE will retain the state of the current Python session so nothing will be "lost". It is entirely possible to re-run parts of their script and re-use the existing state without modifying their code (assuming that the plot function is without side-effects).

@MT0 Alright, if it's Spyder running the program internally, that's different.  Then OP would just need to check whether the huge variable has been already initialized when running that code...

If you have a script in Spyder:
open(bigfile)
bigfile.load(hugevariable)
plot(hugevariable)

and you are running it using the Run command (F5) then it will run the script from the start and, every time, will open the big file and load the data.
Spyder is NOT getting rid of hugevariable between runs and you will be able to see the contents of the variable if you go to the "Variable Explorer" view.

What you want to do is to start running the script from the middle of the script so that you do not have to re-load the data every time.
Either:

Put the cursor on the plot(hugevariable) line (or select the code that you want to run) and use "Run > Run Selection or Current Line" (F9)

Change the code to have cells:
#%% Load the big file
open(bigfile)
bigfile.load(hugevariable)
#%% Plot the data
plot(hugevariable)

A "cell" is a Python comment that starts with #%% and can, optionally, have a descriptive name. In Python, it is just interpreted as a comment but, in the Spyder IDE, it can be used to split a script up into smaller parts so that you can run each "cell" individually.
Then you can use "Run > Run cell" (Ctrl + Enter) or "Run > Run cell and advance" (Shift + Enter) to run the current cell containing the cursor. That way you can repeatedly run the cell that plots the data without having to re-run the cell that loads the data.


